# mgcv: Difference between s(x, by=cat) and s(cat, bs='re')

Tags: linear-regression, mixed-models, gam, mgcv

What is the difference between adding a `by=` parameter to a smooth and adding a random effect smooth?

I've tried both, and get different results. E.g.:

```
library(mgcv)
set.seed(26)
gam.df <- tibble(y=rnorm(400),
                 x1=rnorm(400),
                 cat=factor(rep(1:4, each=100)))
gam0 <- gam(y ~ s(x1, by=cat), data=gam.df)
summary(gam0)
```

produces:

```
15:15:39> summary(gam0)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x1, by = cat)

Parametric coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) -0.001275   0.049087  -0.026    0.979

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
           edf Ref.df     F p-value   
s(x1):cat1   1      1 7.437 0.00667 **
s(x1):cat2   1      1 0.047 0.82935   
s(x1):cat3   1      1 0.393 0.53099   
s(x1):cat4   1      1 0.019 0.89015   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.00968   Deviance explained = 1.96%
GCV = 0.97413  Scale est. = 0.96195   n = 400
```

On the other hand:

```
gam1 <- gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(cat, bs='re'), data=gam.df)
summary(gam1)
```

produces:

```
15:16:33> summary(gam1)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
y ~ s(x1) + s(cat, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept) 0.0001211  0.0572271   0.002    0.998

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
          edf Ref.df     F p-value
s(x1)  1.0000      1 2.359   0.125
s(cat) 0.7883      3 0.356   0.256

R-sq.(adj) =  0.00594   Deviance explained = 1.04%
GCV = 0.97236  Scale est. = 0.96558   n = 400
```

I understand that `by=` shows the summary by each factor level, but shouldn't the overall results of the model such as R^2 be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factor `by` model, `gam0`, contains a *separate* smooth of `x1` for each level of `cat`, but doesn't include anything specifically for the means of `y` in each group[*] because it is miss-specified. Compare this with `gam1`, which has a *single* smooth of `x1` plus group means for the levels of `cat`.

Even though you generated random data without any smooth or group level effects, the `gam0` model is potentially much more complex and flexible a model as it contains 4 separate smooths, each using potentially 9 degrees of freedom. Your `gam1` has a single smooth of `x1` which uses up to 9 degrees of freedom, plus something between 4 and 0 degrees of freedom for the random effect smooth. `gam0` is simply exploiting random variation in the data that can be explained a little bit by those extra potential degrees of freedom. You can see this in the adjusted `R-sq.(adj)`, which is lower for `gam0` despite it explaining ~ twice the deviance as does `gam1` (not that either is a good amount of deviance explained).

```r
r$> library("gratia")                                                           

r$> smooths(gam0)                                                               
[1] "s(x1):cat1" "s(x1):cat2" "s(x1):cat3" "s(x1):cat4"

r$> smooths(gam1)                                                               
[1] "s(x1)"  "s(cat)"
```

[*] Note that your `by` model should be

```r
gam0 <- gam(y ~ cat + s(x1, by=cat), data=gam.df)
```

because the smooths created by `s(x1, by=cat)` are subject to an identifiability constraint (as there's a constant term — the intercept — in the model). This constraint is a sum-to-zero constraint which means that the individual smooths do not contain the group means. This forces the smooths to not only model the way Y changes as a function of `x1` in each group but also model the magnitude of Y in the respective groups, but without functions in the span of the basis that could model such constant (magnitude) effects.

Comment: This is really helpful! Thank you so much. Would there be any advantage to using a factor smooth basis rather than random effect?

Comment: A random effect (`bs = "re"`) only includes a group random effects (random intercepts or parametric terms per group), while a factor-smooth basis (`bs = "fs"`) includes a random intercept, linear slope, and smooth per group. They are not the same thing and aren't really comparable; which you chose comes down to what model you want to fit.

Comment: Got it, thanks! For a by-subject control, do you have any recommendations? Alternatively, is there an accessible explanation of the differences?

Comment: I'm really not sure what you mean - if you mean having a random smooth for repeated observations on the same set of subjects, then take a look at this paper https://doi.org/10.7717/peerj.6876 that colleagues I wrote which tries to explain some of this stuff